# DBCC SQL Server 2000 sysindexkeys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, dbcc

I have a SQL Server 2000 database. When I run the following command

select * from sysindexkeys

This display the appropriate records.

I then do a DBCC command for the sysindexkeys. It doesn't display anything. Strange there is no page having the sysindexkeys records. Then how the query display the list of records.

Comment: Would mean DBCC Ind I suspect

Comment: you're writing a tool for SQL 2000? Given that it's 2010, is it worth the efort?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting

Paul Randall wrote DBCC and [he filtered out (see comment)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/01/17/fragmentation-on-the-system-tables.aspx) system tables for some commands... but nothing on [his blog](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/DBCC.aspx)